# Laravel rename collection keys

Tags: php, laravel, collections, php-7, laravel-8

I have the following line to get an array of collections.

```php
$tags = Tag::all()->map->only(['id', 'name']);
```

Which produces the following data.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"tag 2"},{"id":2,"name":"tag 3"},{"id":3,"name":"tag-44"},{"id":4,"name":"biyoloji"}]
```

My objective is to rename the key names inside the collections as follows.

```
[{"value":1,"text":"tag 2"},{"value":2,"text":"tag 3"},{"value":3,"text":"tag-44"},{"value":4,"text":"biyoloji"}]
```

Basically, I want to rename "key" to "value" and "name" to "text." I tried the `pluck()` function, `get()` function, mapping but couldn't get it to work. Most probably, iterating over it with foreach and `toArray()` would do the trick, but I'm looking for the proper way to do it. My environment is Laravel 8 with PHP 7.4

Comment: you could just alias the columns in the select statement for the query and have them returned named how you want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way I can propose:

```php
$tags = Tag::query()->get(['id', 'name'])
   ->map(function($tag){
        return [
           'value' => $tag->id,
           'text' => $tag->name,
        ];
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Pay attention to `get(['id', 'name])` invoking. Passing required fields to `get` method helps improving query performance. Specially if there are lots of unused columns in the table.

Comment: Spot on solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this via your query more efficiently

```
$tags = Tag::get(['id as value', 'name as text']);
```

Comment: Looks amazing. i want to try it out